# Aviary/Adobe Creative SDK Image component - Image Editor UI: Authentication and login

Tags: ios, image, sdk, editor, adobe

I was wondering if anyone (possibly Adobe/Aviary) could clarify something for us. Our startup is looking at an photo enhancer/editor - and I'm curious about the Adobe Image Editor UI, but was quite put off by making users have and Adobe account and having to log in. I have looked at all the documentation, sample code and it all points to the "Integrating the Authentication Component" here https://creativesdk.adobe.com/docs/ios/#/articles/gettingstarted/index.html. Is not the client-id/client-secret enough to know the billing scenario for us?

In fact, even ONE external login would kill user experience for our offering.I understand that the Cloud components would require separate logins, but we just want Image Editor UI, nothing else (and willing to pay for this obviously).

What I want to know is, would the users of our app have to login and manage login state (with adobe) every time they want to use the Image Editor? If anyone could point me to the right documentation it would be great. I plan to write the wrappers for React Native once I can confirm this (yes, I'll open source it as well once I'm done).

Thanks

Comment: Any process with the open source wrapper?

Comment: How did the wrapper go? Would be amazing :)

Answer (score 2):

No need any user login.

You see this login screen since you are in `DEVELOPMENT MODE`, in release mode you won't see this.

To see how it's really works on production (release) mode, see [some app that using this image editor](https://creativesdk.adobe.com/features/#/creative-tools.html).